# Queue with array given user input

Tags: c#, arrays, queue

After looking at some online tutorials, I've been trying to write a Queue algorithm using an array, the numbers in the array are from user input. When I run the program the delete option doesn't appear to be working correctly as the first time I run the delete option it always says the value is 0, but as well as this when continue the delete option it always deletes the last value inputted, not the first.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace queue_test
 {
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int max = 10;
        int []a;//array
        a = new int[max + 1];
        int b; //user input
        int front = 0;
        int rear = 0;

        int j = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine
                 ("What do you want to do?");

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Add = 1");
            Console.WriteLine("Delete = 2");
            Console.WriteLine("Exit = 3");

            Console.WriteLine();

            b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine();

            if (b == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You selected to Add");

                if (rear == max)
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("The Queue is full");

            }

            else
                Console.WriteLine("What value do you want to add?");

            int v; //value
            v = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            j++;
                a[j] = v;
            rear++;
        }

           else if (b == 2)

        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You selected to Delete");


                if (front == rear)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Queue is empty");
                }

                else

                    Console.WriteLine("The deleted value is:" + a[front++]);

            }

         else if (b == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exit program");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(0);

            }
            else

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a matching option");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        } while (b != 'X') ;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn more about what happens when code executes and help you write better code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statements need to be rearranged in **Add** block as shown below (j++ operation needs to be moved next to a[j] = v operation):

```
int v; //value
v = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
a[j] = v;
j++;
rear++;
```